# Ajax syntax : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error , Why ?
I think i have used the syntax properly ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "loadcontent1.php",
    data: {
        lastid: '$(".postitem").size()',
        location: '$("#location").val()',
        rstatus: '$("#rstatus").val()',
        gender: '$("#gender").val()'
    }
    success: function(html) {
        Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
        if (html) {
            $("#contentwrapper").append(html);
            $('div#ajaxloader').hide();

            $("#contentwrapper").masonry('reload');
            FB.XFBML.parse();

        } else {
            $('div#ajaxloader').html('<center>No more Images.</center>');
        }

    }
});​
```

Comment: As an aside, are you sure you want quotes around `$(".postitem").size()` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "Ajax syntax".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You left off the comma after the `data`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "loadcontent1.php",
    data: {
        lastid: $(".postitem").size(),
        location: $("#location").val(),
        rstatus: $("#rstatus").val(),
        gender: $("#gender").val() // not strings!
    }//, comma here!
    success: function(html) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You are sending up strings with the jQuery code and you are mising a comma

```
data: {
    lastid: '$(".postitem").size()',  <--no single quotes
    location: '$("#location").val()', <--no single quotes
    rstatus: '$("#rstatus").val()', <--no single quotes
    gender: '$("#gender").val()' <--no single quotes
}  <--no comma
```

with it fixed it should be

```
data: {
    lastid: $(".postitem").size(), 
    location: $("#location").val(),
    rstatus: $("#rstatus").val(),
    gender: $("#gender").val() 
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing a comma between your closing curly brace and success:.

Answer (score 1):

A comma is missing before `"success"`